# Violation of primary keys when creating a new record with Entity Framework

Tags: c#, entity-framework, asp.net-mvc-4

Utter greenhorn here! It has already devoured me a few hours, but - I hope - for you it will be a piece of cake. I have had to first create a database (containing a single table `book`) and then automatically implement a basic CRUD functionality with Entity Framework. The table does have its primary key defined!

My problem apparently lies in the way IDs are being generated. Starting with an empty database, I got no exception adding the first record, but cannot add the next one and the `db.SaveChanges()` instruction within `Create` function of `BookController` throws `DbUpdateException`:

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Create(book book)
{
    if (ModelState.IsValid)
    {
        db.book.Add(book);
        db.SaveChanges();
        return RedirectToAction("Index");
    }

    return View(book);
}
```

The internal exception goes as follows:

> Violation of PRIMARY KEY constraint 'PK_book'. Cannot insert duplicate
>   key in object 'dbo.book'. The statement has been terminated.

I have changed the part of the generated context by adding two annotations before the ID definition, but it still doesn't work.

```
public partial class book
{
    [Key] // added
    [DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Computed)] // added
    public int ID { get; set; }

    public string title { get; set; }
    public string author { get; set; }
    public Nullable<int> pages { get; set; }
    public Nullable<double> price { get; set; }
    public Nullable<System.DateTime> date { get; set; }
    public Nullable<bool> access { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: this error is means that you are entering the same value for ID twice. Since ID is the key it must be unique.

Comment: @FahadJameel. Yes, I know. I simply thought adding the annotations is enough. On the other hand, I'm not sure how the cooperation of db with app looks like ... Does one have to specify it explicitly somehow in the db? If so, then how?

Comment: Do you have the auto ID functionality setup in your DB?

Comment: Try using DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity and set  int ID { get; PRIVATE set; }

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To set auto-increment to your database `Key` you can set the `Identity` property to your table definition.

```
[ID]   INT   IDENTITY (1, 1) NOT NULL
```

Or change the ID attribute to:

```
[Key]  
[DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
public int ID { get; set; }
```